# "FFMPEG not found" even though ffmpeg-binaries have been added to the package.json

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, ffmpeg, discord.js

I keep my bot online using Heroku, so installing FFMPEG to my computer wouldn't really help me any.

The issue is that I'm still getting this error despite having the npm `ffmpeg-binaries` added to my package.json's dependencies. I've also tried using git URLs from Github and the official FFMPEG website, as well as trying to install the git directly using the run-command option in Heroku's application page, but I keep getting this same error. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is that ffmpeg directory is not on the PATH.
You should use the absolute path to the ffmpeg executable that is in the node_modules directory. If you require ffmpeg-binaries you will get the absolute path.

```js
const ffmpegPath = require('ffmpeg-binaries');
spawn(ffmpegPath, ['-i', 'video.mkv', 'video.mp4']);
```

Also, note that ffmpeg-binaries install platform-specific binaries, so you should do `npm install` on the target platform or use another package such as `ffmpeg-static` that contains binaries for all supported platforms.